# 'sudo VBoxManage startvm "myWinVM"' returns errors

Tags: virtualbox

`[myuser@localhost ~]$ VBoxManage startvm "myWinVM"` launches fine the VM.

`[myuser@localhost ~]$ sudo VBoxManage startvm "myWinVM"` returns a number of errors:

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'myWinVM'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(pszVM).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 721 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

why so?

I am on a Fedora 35 machine; VirtualBox 6.1.32 (rpmfusion r149290);
Guest OS, Win 7 (64-bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` runs things as root.  "myuser" has a vbox VM called "myWinVM", but root does not.

Why would you even want to run it as root, anyway?   The only good reason to use virtualbox over Linux's own [KVM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) is that it makes it easy to run VMs as a normal user without any special privileges.

Comment: do I have a wrong assumption: whatever a user can do, root can do too? (I was not aware of KVM, nice to know, thanks)

Comment: a user's files (including their config files and VM images) are in their home directory - usually something like `/home/username`.  root has its own home directory (on linux distros, typically `/root`. on paleo-unixes, usually `/`).   By default, vbox looks for VM images under the home dir of the user who runs it  (you can configure it otherwise, or you can override it one the command line) - so, when run as root, it looks for VM images under ~root/